# Explanation of a formula for spherical 3d tag cloud

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am not an expert in mathematics, I am only a young programmer.
I am trying to construct a spherical tag cloud and I've found this formula:

```
for i,t in enumerate(tags)
    phi = acos((2* (i+1) -1) / tag_num -1)
    theta = sqrt(tag_num * pi) * phi

    x = radius * cos(theta) * sin(phi)
    y = radius * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
    z = radius * cos(phi)

    t.setPosition(x,y,z)
```

and it works fine.
but I thought, for a spherical disposition, have to do 2 nested for:
one for latitude and one for longitude.
What kind of formula do I use in  these codes? Can you explain me what this `acos` and `sqrt` do?

Comment: I can't quite see where the `i` and `tag_num` came from, and an angle with a $\sqrt \pi$ factor sounds fishy to me. In any event the effort in `z` looks wasted, since you have an arccosine and then a cosine... where precisely did you find these bits?

Comment: You may find the blog post [How I made wine glasses from sunflowers](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/) by Cris Carlson very relevant.

Comment: @J.M. tag_num is the total number of tag, and i is a paramater that goes from 0 to num_tag-1

Comment: I'm going to repeat J.M.'s last question and ask again, where exactly did you find this formula?

Comment: is it so important? i found it here: http://wonderfl.net/c/n2ly and the formula is at line 72

Comment: Why do you think it isn't important to cite your sources?

Comment: does that source help you in finding an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The number of nested `for` loop reflects the dimensionality of the *input*, not *output*.

You would need two `for` loops if you were to iterate over points on a sphere, e.g., taking the temperature at various places on the globe. In this case the input space is two-dimensional (surface of the sphere). The fact that the output (temperature) is a scalar does not matter. If you sample temperature, humidity, and pressure (thus outputting a 3d vector), you still run only two nested `for` loops to cover the sphere.

In your problem the input is a one-dimensional array of tags, while the output consists of points on a sphere. As the tags come one by one in the `for` loop, the code places them on a sphere. A naive idea would be something like 
$\phi=\pi i/n$, $\theta=2\pi i/n$ where $n$ is the number of tags and $i$ is the index of the current tag. But this would result in all tags lying along the curve $\theta=2\phi$ on the sphere, which would not look nice. To distribute the tags uniformly, it suffices to break the pattern in either $\phi$ or $\theta$.

The code keeps a simple pattern in  $\phi$: they decrease steadily, so as to make the $z$-coordinates grow from `-radius` to `radius`. The purpose of formula with `acos` is to produce values of $\phi$ which will later make $z$ equally spaces (because $z$ involves $\cos\phi$). Then the code does something pretty wierd with $\theta$, using a factor of $\sqrt{\pi n}$. I think all that matters here is that $\sqrt{\pi n}$ is a large irrational number. There's a good chance that the author of the code tried something different first, did not like the result, slapped the square root on the formula, and saw that it's better this way. I don't think this appearance of `sqrt` is related to the sunflower algorithm linked to by Sasha, because we don't have the index $i$ under `sqrt`, just a constant.